# Error with adding dynamic field in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to adding row of field dynamically when the add button is clicked. It works fine. The problem is when I click the add button it clear the first row values and add the new row. The code what I did is given below.

HTML:

```
<div id="ruleCriteria" style="padding: 20px;width: 100%;">
  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="evaluationCriteriaCondition">
    Slide me!
  </mat-slide-toggle>
  <div id="ruleCriteriaFielDev" *ngFor="let ruleArray of ruleArrays; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field style="width: 30%">
      <mat-select [(value)]="selected[i]" [(ngModel)]="ruleArrays[i].field" formControlName="evaluationRuleField" id="evaluationRuleField" placeholder="Select value" name="evaluationRuleField">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let evaluationRuleField of evaluationRuleFields" [value]="evaluationRuleField.value">
          {{evaluationRuleField.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field style="width: 30%">
      <mat-select formControlName="evaluationRuleOperator" [(ngModel)]="ruleArrays[i].operator" placeholder="Operation"  id="evaluationRuleOperator" name="evaluationRuleOperator" required>
        <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let operator of operators" [value]="operator.value">
          {{ operator.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%">
      <input matInput formControlName="evaluationRuleValue" placeholder="Enter Value" [(ngModel)]="ruleArrays[i].ruleFieldvalue"id="evaluationRuleValue" name="evaluationRuleValue" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="addRuleRow(i)">+</button>
    <button mat-button *ngIf="i > 0" (click)="deleteRuleRow(i)">x</button>
    <mat-divider style="border-width: 6px;background:lightblue"></mat-divider>
  </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
private ruleArrays: Array<any> = [{field:"",operator:"",ruleFieldvalue:""}];

private newAttribute: any = {}

 evaluationRuleFields = [
    { value: "field_1", valueFieldType: 'text', viewValue: "Field 1" },
    { value: "field_2", valueFieldType: 'dropdown', viewValue: "Field 2" },
    { value: "field_3", valueFieldType: 'text', viewValue: "Field 3" },
    { value: "field_4", valueFieldType: 'multiselect', viewValue: "Field 4" },
    { value: "field_5", valueFieldType: 'dropdown', viewValue: "Field 5" }
  ]

  operators = [
    { value: "equals", viewValue: "Equals" },
    { value: "notequalto", viewValue: "Not Equalto" },
    { value: "contains", viewValue: "contains" },
    {
  ]

addRuleRow() {
    this.ruleArrays.push(this.newAttribute)
}
```

Comment: why are you pushing empty new Attribute object for first click

Comment: for creating next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
addRuleRow(item) {
    this.ruleArrays.push(item)
}
```